# Which structured data type for tide information on AMP pages?

Tags: seo, schema.org, structured-data, amp

I have a website which displays tide times for various locations, and recently added AMP (accelerated mobile pages) content. Currently, there is no structured data, and Google have made a recommendation in Search Console to add some.

The guidelines that Google have documented at https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/use-AMP-HTML state in the top stories carousel requirements (which I'd like my data to appear):

> Structured data for one of the following types: Article, NewsArticle, BlogPosting, VideoObject

Technically, tide times for a given location don't fall under any, but it is relevant information for a search of a given location (just like the weather is). My question is:

Which should I implement, I personally feel `Article` or `NewsArticle` is relevant, especially `NewsArticle`. By definition, news is "newly received or noteworthy information, especially about recent events" which I would argue tide information falls under.

I'm keen to avoid either being labelled as a spammy source by Google and co, but at the same time, especially growing up in a seaside community, tidal information is absolutely relevant for a given location.

Comment: You should not use structured data just for the sake of using it.   Structured data is useful when you know that somebody needs to consume the data from your website in a machine readable way.  For some data, search engines use it to provide "rich snippets" in the search results.   However, there is no rich snippet for tide data.  It is such a narrow niche, that there likely never will be.   There is no ranking boost associated with using rich snippets, only a change in how the site is displayed in the search results for some specific uses. You just don't need to use structured data at all.